# Setup .pkla rule for polkit

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, d-bus, polkit

I'd like to start a systemd service using DBus in one of my apps which is run as non-root user `myuser`. For that I need to set up a PolicyKit where I'm using polkit 0.105 and added the following .pkla file to `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d`

```
Identity=unix-user:myuser
Action=org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files;org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units
ResultActive=yes
ResultInactive=yes
```

Hoewever, that somehow didn't help it as I'm still getting the error `Permission denied` from DBus when it's runned as `myuser` where it works when started by `root`.

As I understood polkit so far that's actually the way to set it up.

What wonders me as well is that when executing `pkaction` it just returns nothing.

Does `polkit` need some further setup? I just installed it via `apt-get` on an ubunutu 19.04 box.

Answer (score 0):

In org.freedesktop.systemd1.policy for :

```
action id="org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units"
action id="org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files"
```

try to replace the line

```
<allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
```

by :

```
<allow_active>yes</allow_active>
```

Comment: Thanks @ctac_. Though `busctl call org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager StartUnit ss "myservice.service" "replace"` still yields `Access Denied`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand ! Don't know enough about systemd.